# My Rails server only works when the pg gem is uninstalled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, postgresql, rubygems

I'm quite new to Ruby (and Rails) and I've been trying to set up a Rails server that accesses a PostgresQL database on Windows. I apologize in advance if I'm missing something obvious. I am using the most recent Windows release of Ruby 2.3.0p0, and the most recent PostgresQL version, 9.6 Beta 2.

I've been following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-ruby-on-rails-application-on-ubuntu-14-04) somewhat loosely, as it is written for Ubuntu. I installed Ruby, the Rails gem and dependencies without a hitch. Basically, everything goes fine until I go to run the

```
rails server
```

command, and my command prompt complains that the specified module can't be found. I had the pg gem installed, so I tried a variety of fixes I found, such as putting libpq.dll in the ruby/bin folder, creating a 2.3 folder, and so on. Nothing worked until I removed the actual pg gem itself, whereupon my server magically booted up. I suspect that the pg gem was overriding the pg version installed by the

```
bundle install
```

command automatically run after the

```
gem install pg
```

but I'm not actually sure what was going on. Could someone clue me in on the details?

EDIT, some debugging info:
With the vanilla pg gem, rails s gives:

```
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.18.4-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:14:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.3/pg_ext
```

After copying the 2.2 folder to a 2.3 folder, rails s gives:

```
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.18.4-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:14:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.18.4-x64-mingw32/lib/2.3/pg_ext.so (LoadError)
```

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: website_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: website_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: website_production
  username: website
  password: <%= ENV['WEBSITE_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

I haven't actually linked the database to Rails yet; I wanted to make sure the Rails side was actually working first.

EDIT2:

I realized that MarsAtomic said PATH and not LOADPATH, and I realized that ruby wasn't in my PATH for some reason. However, it still doesn't work after adding ruby/bin to my PATH. I'm beginning to think that Windows is rejecting the .so file or something, because when I put a .rb file in the same location, it finds that without problem. I also ran file on the .dll and .so, and it reports that they are both PE32+, and my ruby is also 64-bit, so I don't think it's an architecture issue either.

Comment: How about giving us the exact error message you encountered? Also, post your `gemfile` and your `database.yml`. It would help to know the version of your Postgres DB (is it a pre-existing database, or did you install it specifically for your Rails app?).

Comment: Okay, I added some new information to the OP.

Comment: What you're seeing is strange, but then, you're on Windows... Do you have libpq.dll on your PATH?

Comment: I tried adding libpq.dll to ruby/bin as well as different locations in my PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't an architecture thing, but it was close. I believe the reason it couldn't load the module is because the pg_ext.so in question was compiled for Ruby 2.2 and I am using Ruby 2.3. Upgrading to pg 0.19-pre seemed to resolve the issue.

EDIT: I just found out how to build native extensions and I tried it out the pg 0.18.4 package. (extconf.rb -> devkit's make). I took the .so that was generated and placed it in the 2.3 folder. It didn't ask for the .def but I might need it once I actually link to my database.

Answer (score 0):

If not working on `gem 'pg'` then try to `gem 'postgresql'` OR `gem install postgresql` just see working properly or no

Thanks

Comment: It works fine as long as there isn't pg installed, so gem install postgresql works, but I don't think it's actually being used.